# P - bounded polyhedron, L - linear map. Show that L(P) is a bounded polyhedron

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, polyhedra

Let $P = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n \ | \ Ax\leq b\}$ be a bounded polyhedron. Let $L:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ be a linear map.
Show that $L(P):=\{L(x)\ | \ x\in P\}$ is a bounded polyhedron.

I understand that polyhedral sets are preserved by images and preimages under linear transformations.

To prove it I need to use the fact that the linear map can be represented as a matrix, but I am still not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $L$ is a mapping between finite-dimensional vector spaces, it is bounded. That is, there exists a number $\|L\|$ such that
$$
\|Lx\|\le \|L\|\cdot \|x\|\quad \forall x\in X.
$$
Here, $\|x\|$ is the Euclidean norm of $x$ (could be any other vector norm as well).
Since $P$ is bounded, there is $M>0$ such that $\|x\|\le M$ for all $x\in P$. 
This implies that
$$
\|Lx\| \le \|L\|\cdot \|x\| \le \|L\|\cdot M \forall x\in P,
$$ 
and $L(P)$ is bounded.